# how to prevent variable from being re-rendered inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have the following problem: I have an editor written, here is a short snippet:

```
        <div
            id="editor-container"
            className="ps-relative s-textarea p0 d-flex fd-column"
            style={{ width: "1500px", zIndex: 10 }}
        >
            <div className="js-sticky py6 bg-inherit btr-sm w100 ps-sticky t0 l0 z-nav s-editor-shadow js-plugin-container js-sticky">
                <MenuBar
                    editor={editor as Editor}
                    onViewChanged={setIsCodeViewMode}
                />
            </div>
            <div
                id="editor-content"
                className={`overflow-scroll fl-grow1 outline-none p12 pt6 w100 s-prose js-editor ProseMirror ${
                    !isCodeViewMode ? "" : "d-none"
                }`}
            >
                <EditorContent editor={editor} />
            </div>

            <div
                className={`mw-editor__codemirror ${isCodeViewMode ? "" : "d-none"}`}
            >
                <textarea
                    ref={cmTextAreaRef}
                    style={{ width: "100%", margin: 0, padding: 0, border: "initial" }}
                ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here `MenuBar` is a component which contains all the buttons and `div` with`textarea` is shown only when `isCodeViewMode` state is true (there is a button to toggle this state value)

Above this, there is the following piece of code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (!editor) return;
        let cmInstace;

        const codeView = (editor as Editor).extensionManager.extensions.find(
            (e) => e.name === "code_view"
        );

        if (codeView && !cmInstance) {
            const { codemirror, codemirrorOptions } = codeView.options;
            if (codemirror) {
                // merge options
                const cmOptions = {
                    ...codemirrorOptions,
                    readOnly: !(editor as Editor).isEditable,
                };
                cmInstance = codemirror.fromTextArea(cmTextAreaRef.current, cmOptions);
            }
        }

        if (isCodeViewMode) {
            cmInstance.setValue((editor as Editor).getHTML()); // init content
            // Format code
            cmInstance.execCommand("selectAll");
            const selectedRange = {
                from: cmInstance.getCursor(true),
                to: cmInstance.getCursor(false),
            };
            cmInstance.autoFormatRange(selectedRange.from, selectedRange.to);
            cmInstance.setCursor(0);
        } else {
            const content = cmInstance.getValue();
            (editor as Editor).commands.setContent(content, true);
            // Destroy code mirror
            const element = cmInstance.doc.cm.getWrapperElement();
            element && element.remove && element.remove();
            cmInstance = null;
        }
    }, [isCodeViewMode]);
```

So depending on the value of `isCodeViewMode`, different content is set. The problem is that `cmInstance` is set to null each time when `useEffect` is called. I would like to somehow cache it somehow so that if `useEffect` is called for the second time, `cmInstance` from earlier run is used instead of creating new one. So:

1. When called for the first time, `cmInstance = codemirror.fromTextArea(cmTextAreaRef.current, cmOptions);` is executed
2. If `isCodeViewMode` is false, this instance is used to get its content and it's cleared (set to `null`) so that the next (3rd) time the function is called, again `cmInstance = codemirror.fromTextArea(cmTextAreaRef.current, cmOptions);`

How can I achieve that?